# Bootstrap navbar not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have the following `nav` code (see below) and it's not working.

Specifically, the links simply aren't showing up at all. When I shrink the screen, the icon-bars show up, but, when I click on them, nothing appears. It's like the entire `nav-collapse` div is hidden somehow.

I tried to make a JSFiddle, but it looked even worse and I think it's because I'm not sure how to add Bootstrap to JSFiddle.

I also am adding some styling to the navbar elements. Below is the relevant `CSS` in case that may be the culprit somehow.

```css
.navbar {
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #333;
}

.navbar-inner {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.navbar .container {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.nav-collapse {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  color: #355E3B;
  z-index: 20;
}

.collapse {
  background-color: #D2B48C;
}

.nav-collapse ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-collapse ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #355E3B;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbutton {
  padding: 0 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #D2B48C;
  color: #355E3B;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul>
          <li class="navbutton" id="home_button">home</li>
          <li class="navbutton" id="services_button">services</li>
          <li class="navbutton" id="facility_button">facility</li>
          <li class="navbutton" id="trainers_button">trainers</li>
          <li class="navbutton" id="contact_button">contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT!!!

While I was going to the latest CSS Bootstrap files, I apparently neglected to link to the latest Bootstrap JS file! I included that and the nav works. I still need to clean it up a little, but now I can see it at least to do that!

Thanks all for your assistance!

Comment: In my case I was missing popper (which is part of bootstrap.bundle.min.js)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the html from the [bootstrap example page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), it looks like you are missing `navbar-header`. Make sure you follow the html correctly.

```
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: This *almost* does it. The nav items show up again and work, but a) they start moving to next line on screen sizing before they disappear - how can I change the width at which they switch? also, b) when they disappear, I don't see the icon-bars show up. I found a theoretically clickable spot in teh middle of the navbar, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Hmm. So, some progress. I get the iconbars to show up, but nothing when I click them. Here's the thing, though. When I drop them into a JSFiddle - it works. Also, when I cut and paste the example from bootstrap to my page, it doesn't work. Now I need to figure out what on my page is killing it!

Comment: You could change the padding on the list items. Otherwise, you would want to change the breakpoints if you want the menu to collapse earlier. Read up on less or if you're using the sass version, you could change the variables before recompiling to what you need. Remove all of your own css unless its necessary.

Comment: I got the collapsing breakpoint working now. The only thing left is to figure out what's stopping the menu from displaying when I click on the icon-bar. I'll post if I figure it out.  Thanks all!

Comment: Heh. I spoke too soon. When I shrink my browser on my desktop, the div collapses. When I view the page on my phone, it doesn't. Bah!

Comment: You should be having this issues if you installed and are using the correct html. Go to the bootstrap site and take a look at their examples. Copy it verbatim and start with that, once you have the responsiveness working, start adding your content back in.

Comment: I literally copied their code and removed all my CSS and the very same code that works on their site, doesn't on mine.  I'm lost.  Here's my page:  http://primary.gelerinter.com/dev_sites/pinegrove/template.php If anyone can figure it out, I'd be impressed and grateful!

Comment: Make sure you JS isn't breaking, you have a 404 loading, make sure that jquery is loading ok

Comment: I don't understand. It all loads fine when I load it up. The JS functionality works fine when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which version of Bootstrap you are using, I suppose 3.x. But your code doesn't fit Bootstrap's standard.
I think the `icon-bar`, to toggle navigation, have to be in a navbar-header. Also I don't know (maybe you can) if you can `data-target` on a class.

You should try this code :

```
<div class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleId">
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySite</a> -->
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleId">
                <ul>
                    <li class="navbutton" id="home_button"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbutton" id="services_button"><a href="#">services</a></li>
                    <li class="navbutton" id="facility_button"><a href="#">facility</a></li>
                    <li class="navbutton" id="trainers_button"><a href="#">trainers</a></li>
                    <li class="navbutton" id="contact_button"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has the same issues as the other answer and it also make the menu items stack like a regular UL. :(